# Tensorflow cannon import name 'gradients_util'

Tags: python, tensorflow

After doing

> `pip install tensorflow-gpu`

I am trying to

> `import gradients_util from tensorflow.python.ops`

but I get

> `cannot import name 'gradients_util'`

error. How can I fix this?

Comment: There is no such module `gradients_util` in TensorFlow's [public API](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf). Why were you trying to import this module? Can we see where you would be using it?

Comment: This module is inside official tensorflow repository though. I am trying to benchmark tf on distributed machine using https://github.com/tensorflow/benchmarks/tree/master/scripts/tf_cnn_benchmarks

Comment: That does not mean that it's part of the public API. You should avoid using such modules. Usually there are better abstractions for the same functionality.

Comment: There is a `tensorflow.python.ops.gradients_util` module in the source, but it is part of [a change not integrated into a stable version](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/4c08b96795a1b3367ebbb676c00201318122ecd0#diff-282e88a363277853ba91cd4b3dba434d), seemingly towards TensorFlow 2.x. You may try with [`tf-nightly`](https://pypi.org/project/tf-nightly/)/[`tf-nightly-gpu`](https://pypi.org/project/tf-nightly-gpu/) or [`tf-nightly-2.0-preview`](https://pypi.org/project/tf-nightly-2.0-preview/)/[`tf-nightly-gpu-2.0-preview`](https://pypi.org/project/tf-nightly-gpu-2.0-preview/).

Comment: (Note that [TensorFlow 2.x comes with several important changes](https://medium.com/tensorflow/whats-coming-in-tensorflow-2-0-d3663832e9b8) though, so you may prefer to try this on a different virtual environment)

Comment: Thanks, jdehesa! Seems to be working now.

Answer (score 2):

You must use version of benchmark compatible with your TensorFlow version.
Determine it using `pip show tensorflow`.

Then go to cloned repository of benchmarks, and checkout to required branch, for example `git checkout cnn_tf_v1.13_compatible`.

Previous comments suggested to use TensorFlow 2.0, but I don't think author of question needs it, as long as it's still unreleased and has a lot of API-breaking changes.

P. S. You should've say that you are trying to launch benchmarks from tensorflow/benchmarks in your question.